# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android' Flutter

Tags: android

I have this error can you tell me what's the solution for it?

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 8174407; received: 4456416
  >   Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5248142; received: 4456416
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21m 37s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether the first time or not. When you click run on your application you get an X gradle build error If you have any of the following lines in your error even a single line then try this solution

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar'.
         > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 8174407; received: 4456416
   > Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar'.
         > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5248142; received: 4456416
```

`SOLUTION`

Go this location:- `.flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`
**

1. **Backup** the file in another place before making edits to it
2. Search for something called `buildscript`;
3. It should come up like that (or similar, don't worry you have a backup file)

and overwrite this code

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

With this

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

Still, your problem is not solved? If it was solved DON'T try the next one if not then try it. (And even if this didn't work then put the backup file in its place and see if it's working)

Then in your `android` folder go to `build.gradle` (in your project files go to 
 `android/build.gradle`) and change the `buildscript` to this (Don't worry about the code not being 100% like this. Just add the specified line in the shown location and that's it)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()  //add this line
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' // Doesn't matter what you have here
    }
}
```

Comment: I've explained every thing in this post: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869466/flutter-app-a-problem-occurred-configuring-root-project-android

Comment: I direcrly tried second option and it worked for me. thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just make **Flutter clean** in android studio or VScode

Answer (score 3):

If you already have `mavenCentral()` added inside `buildscripts{...}` and `allprojects{...}`
inside `build.gradle` file,

then add `jcenter()` after each `mavenCentral()`.

or, vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

If you got **AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin** as well then just focus on following versions:

1. change your compileSdkVersion 30 in app\build.gradel
2. Try to change this accordingly

   dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

   }
3. Try to change gradle version in **gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties**

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in androidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the .gradle folder in C:user/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `.gradle` folder in `C:\Users\<your_username>` solved the problem for me. It simply clears Gradle's cache and local configuration. I tried all other options before trying this and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me, Run this command.

```
find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete
```